# Add custom border to view at runtime

Tags: java, android, xml

I'd like to add a custom border to a listview item when selected, at runtime. But my current minSDK is 11 and I don't want to change it...

So I've created two drawables : `custom_border` and `selected_custom_border`.

Currently, I'm importing them using this :

```
v.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.custom_border));
```

But `View.setBackground` requires API level 16... is there an alternative for this method ?

Comment: if you want to setBackground in API>=16,but it will not work in APII<16 you can use @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICECREAM),else i dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On device with API level lower than 16 you can use [setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

For example:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.custom_border);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    this.setBackground(drawable);
} else {
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
```